# Ranorex Spy - The recognition elements on the page (prioritizing attributes)

Tags: ranorex

I have question related to the Ranorex Spy.
Is it possible to recognize (by default) elements of the page by attribute other than id, e.g. data-id 
I know that I can modify this later manually for each element (but it is time consuming)

Currently:
\input[#id='..."]

Expected (automatically, by Ranorex Spy):
\input[@data-id='..."]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personnally did not bother using this (because we use many frameworks and whats desired in one framework is not necessarily whats desired in another one) but I think you can achieve priorisation of XPath rules using the RanoreXPath Weight Rules.

Following is a Ranorex article describing how to do this: http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/ranorexpath-weight-rule-library.html

Good luck!